# Columns changing to Null after passing through a Merge Join Transformation

Tags: ssis

I have a project where I am migrating data from a DB2 table over to a SQL table.

I pull the data in, then pass the dataset through a Script Transformation to hash each row in the dataset (to be used for comparison later in detecting any updates that need to be made).  After the Script Transformation, I sort both datasets and pass them into a Merge Join Transformation.

Here's the problem that I'm running into.

After passing the sorted datasets into the Merge Join, the resulting Left Outer Join dataset that emerges contains a NULL value for each record in the dataset....and I don't know why?

Here is a picture of my Merge Join Transformation Editor:

[image]

I enabled a data viewer earlier in my project to verify that hashes are being generated for both the Host table and the SQL table. Everything works fine up until after it passes through the Merge Join Transformation.

I have a similar project that does the exact same thing with a different table.  Both are modeled and designed the same, except this one is the only one that is having this particular hiccup with the SQL Hash column.

Does anyone have any thoughts that could help me troubleshoot this?

Comment: I apologize....the NULL value is appearing the field for the SQL generated Hash.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies again.  After doing some digging, apparently EVERY single row that emerged from the Merge Join was a new row and I was searching for the new rows by the wrong column name.  Logic error on my part.